# Error getting the number of tabs in "Terminal" window via Applescript on OSX El Capitan

Tags: bash, terminal, applescript, osx-elcapitan

Basically, I want to change the theme of bash when I open new windows, not new tabs, and then have tabs of a window share the same theme; while themes of separate windows are determined randomly.

After some digging, I found out an applescript which sets the theme of the current tab of Terminal window. I created a

*/usr/local/terminal-color.scpt*  as:

```
on run argv
    tell application "Terminal" to set current settings of selected tab of front window to some settings set
end run
```

And I have added the following statement to my bash profile:

```
osascript /usr/local/terminal-color.scpt
```

Now this script, of course, runs with every new instance of the bash. I cannot do anything about that from bash_profile. However, I should be able to differentiate a new window or a new tab from the applescript itself. Therefore, I am looking for an **if** statement, which would let the script run only when new windows are created. Something like:

```
on run argv
    if index of selected tab is 0
        tell application "Terminal" ....
    end if
end run
```

But I cannot figure out how to achieve this looking at the applescript documentation and scripting dictionary of the terminal application. Help please

**Update**

I try editing the script as follows:

```
set tabNum to number of tabs of front window
if tabNum = 1 then
    tell app ...
```

this won't work either giving an error `tabs of window 1 doesn’t understand the “count” message`

Answer (score 0):

My approach was correct but I had a simple mistake of trying to get tab or window data before choosing an application scope. To put in simple words, first `tell` the application, then ask about its properties. Here's the code that worked:

```
on run argv
    tell application "Terminal"
        if number of tabs of front window = 1 then
            set current settings of selected tab of front window to some settings set
        end if
    end tell
end run
```

**Even Better**

Improving the previous script; this one not randomly chooses a theme, it iterates through your available terminal themes according to the windows you have already open. You can also set your default theme that will be set on your first launch of the terminal. In my case, it was the 5th one in the `settings set`. Here goes the code:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    if number of tabs in front window = 1 then
        set defaultThemeOffset to 5
        set allThemes to number of settings set
        set allWindows to number of windows
        set themeIndex to (defaultThemeOffset + allWindows) mod allThemes
        set current settings of selected tab of front window to settings set themeIndex
    end if
end tell
```